# No PHP processing (Ubuntu/Apache2)

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache2

**EDIT**

```
[Sun Sep 01 18:37:40 2013] [error] [client MY IP ADDRESS] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Sep 01 18:37:40 2013] [error] [client MY IP ADDRESS] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/test2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pe$
```

This is the error that I have in my Apache2 error.log

---

I have set up an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 12.x)

I have performed all updates, installed apache2, php5 & libapache2-mod-php5

The webserver is working fine for .html, I made a test page and tried this, it worked fine.

When I tried to add PHP to my html file though, there is no processing of the php. For example:

```
<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>
```

or (including html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If I were to write some text in the html portion, that would be displayed perfectly.

It is worth noting that there are no errors coming up, I just get a blank screen or only the html elements.

---

I am really confused as to what could have gone wrong here. I played around with a different instance around a month ago, followed the same install and php was working fine then, didn't edit any config files to get it up and running.

I can provide logs and things if requested but i'm not sure which logs would be best to provide. I would rather not set up a fresh instance as I have spent a few hours on this one sorting permissions, users, FTP etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: unless you added the php handler to handle `.html` files it will only process `.php` files, change the extention of your `.html` file to `.php` and test again.

Comment: did you checked to see if `php.load` and `php.conf` are in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`

Comment: @PatrickEvans I changed the filetype to .php and I still get a blank page, no errors.

Comment: @IvanHušnjak Both PHP5.conf and PHP5.load are found in the mods-enabled and mods-available directories. So I don't think it is this.

Comment: is there anything in your error logs

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am now getting error logs: `[Sun Sep 01 18:37:40 2013] [error] [client MY IP] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Sep 01 18:37:40 2013] [error] [client MY IP] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/test2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pe$`

Comment: A link would be great. Also take a look at lines 480 and 501 on /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and make sure error reporting is on and logging is on. Then try loading the page a couple of times. Now look at /var/log/apache2/error.log and tell us if you encounter any error messages and what they were.

Comment: @Austin I have added the relevant entries in the Apache2 error log above. Thank you.

Comment: You can try blindly changing the permissions to 777 to see if that makes it work, but DO NOT leave them like that. It is a security risk. chmod 777 test2.php

Comment: @Austin I set to 755 and that did the trick... Is there a way that I can automatically update the privileges in /var/www ? Im pretty sure that in my previous instance I never had to chmod more than once, but now when I send things over FTP they all end up with the wrong privs. All I can think is that the user than I use for FTP doesnt have the right privs, so files that user writes will always be something that doesn't work... thank you

Comment: @MilesGl as far as I know there isn't a way to automatically update the ownership and privilege settings. It's pretty easy to edit though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your files should be set to use 644 permissions and your directories should be set to use 755. Also the user should be set properly as well to www-data or else the recommended permissions may not work.

```
find /var/www -type d | sudo xargs chmod 755
find /var/www -type f | sudo xargs chmod 644
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in you httpd.conf file there should be an instruction to pass php files to mod_php. For example:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```